# Is it possible to fill a file dialog with the file currently open in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked, however, I was not able to find any information on it myself. I am new to Javascript so I could be overlooking something but essentially I'm trying to change a feature on a Javascript application that uses node.js.

The application allows for digital timing diagrams to be made. When you go to 'Save As...' and it opens up the file dialog, it has a default filename which you can save it as or edit. I was hoping, however, to have it fill in the file dialog with the filename of the current file open (if applicable). 
In the HTML code, they use something along the lines the following line of code to call for the file to be saved. 
`<input style="display:none;" id="fileDialogSave" type="file" nwsaveas="wavedrom.json" />`

As well, on the node.js side of the application (which uses the fs module to save files), the following block of code is the process used to save the file. I understand that I can change the filename variable in the fs.writeFile() line, however, I would like what is being set on the node.js side to reflect in the file dialog that way the filename can still be changed from the default value, as is currently possible.

```
    function saveJSON () {
        var a;

        function sjson () {
            return localStorage.waveform;
        }

        function chooseFile(name) {
            var chooser = document.querySelector(name);

            chooser.addEventListener('change', function() {
                var fs = require('fs');
                var filename = this.value;
                // alert(filename)
                if (!filename) { return; }
                fs.writeFile(filename, sjson(), function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                });
                this.value = '';
            }, false);

            chooser.click();
        }

        if (typeof process === 'object') { // nodewebkit detection
            chooseFile('#fileDialogSave');
        } else {
            var cfse = window.chooseFileSystemEntries;
            if (cfse !== undefined) {
                // PWA: https://web.dev/native-file-system/#write-file
                cfse({
                    type: 'saveFile',
                    accepts: [{
                        description: 'JSON file',
                        extensions: ['json', 'js', 'json5'],
                        mimeType: ['application/json', 'text/javascript', 'text/json5']
                    }]
                }).then(function (fh) {
                    fh.createWriter().then(function (writer) {
                        writer.write(0, sjson()).then(function () {
                            writer.close();
                        });
                    });
                });
            } else {
                a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = 'data:text/json;base64,' + btoa(sjson());
                a.download = 'wavedrom.json';
                var theEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
                theEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                a.dispatchEvent(theEvent);
                a.click();
            }
        }
    }
```

Essentially, the only difference I would like would be for the file dialog to show the current file name instead of a default name (if possible).

Comment: `a.download` should set the default file name in the prompt. Is it not `wavedrom.json`?

Comment: Does this need an [nwjs](https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tag?

Comment: It is ```wavedrom.json``` however I was wondering if it is possible for it to fill the prompt with the file name of the file that is currently open, instead of a default file name. Not sure if this is possible, I’m new to JS. Thank you!